# Azure Maps - fillColor color attributes for different layers merging

Tags: azure-maps

When loading multiple layers, the attribute color for fillColor is merging with fillColor for another layer.  I.e. if one is red and the other is blue, both layers are being displayed on map as purple.

Below is the code that is leading to the issue:

```
        //Wait until the map resources are ready.
        map.events.add('ready', function () {
            //Create a data source and add it to the map.
            datasource = new atlas.source.DataSource();
            map.sources.add(datasource);

            //Add a simple data layer for rendering the data.
            var polygonLayer = new atlas.layer.PolygonLayer(datasource, null, {
                fillColor: 'red',
                fillOpacity: 0.2,
            });


            //Add a simple data layer for rendering the data.
            var polygonLayer2 = new atlas.layer.PolygonLayer(datasource, null, {
                fillColor: 'blue',
                fillOpacity: 0.2,
            });


            //Add a simple data layer for rendering the data.
            var lineLayer = new atlas.layer.LineLayer(datasource, null, {
                strokeColor: 'black',
            });

            map.layers.add([polygonLayer, polygonLayer2, lineLayer]);


            //Read a KML file from a URL or pass in a raw KML string.
            atlas.io.read(window.location.origin + '/data/TOC_WGS_KML.kml').then(r => {
                if (r) {
                    //Add the feature data to the data source.
                    datasource.add(r);

                }
            });

            //Read a KML file from a URL or pass in a raw KML string.
            atlas.io.read(window.location.origin + '/data/OZLA.kml').then(r => {
                if (r) {
                    //Add the feature data to the data source.
                    datasource.add(r);

                }
            });

            //Read a KML file from a URL or pass in a raw KML string.
            atlas.io.read(window.location.origin + '/data/Test-Parcels.kml').then(r => {
                if (r) {
                    //Add the feature data to the data source.
                    datasource.add(r);

                }
            });


        });
```

Answer (score 1):

That is to be expected. You have two polygon layers rendering the exact same data (twice) with semi-transparent colors.

If you want to render data from one of your files differently from another, you can either use a data driven style expression for the fillColor that looks at properties of your shapes to determine which color to use, or you can use two data sources, each with their own polygon layer. That said, if the polygons are semi-transparent and overlap, you will see the colors merge still.